# PhP Select not sending value

Tags: php, sql, forms, select, fetch

```
                <?php

                    include ("forms/coneccao_feed.php");
                        $query = "SELECT id as ID, nome as Nome FROM provedor";
                        $query1= "Select MAX(id) as ID From provedor";
                        $ultprovedor = mysqli_query ($ligacao_feed, $query1);
                        $ultimo_provedor = mysqli_fetch_row($ultprovedor);
                        $provedores = mysqli_query($ligacao_feed, $query);
                        ?>
                            <select name="provedor">
                            <?php
                                while($provedor=mysqli_fetch_array($provedores)){                               
                                    if ($provedor['ID'] == $ultimo_provedor['0']){                              
                                    ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $provedor['ID']; ?>" selected><?php echo $provedor['Nome'] ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                                }else{                              
                                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $provedor['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $provedor['Nome'] ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                                }
                                }?>
                            </select>
```

I searched everywhere but cant find an answer, when I submit it does not send anything, and i tried to echo in the form but it also does nothing.

```
        <?php
            include ("forms/coneccao_feed.php");
            $id_provedor = $_POST['id'];
            $mensagem = $_POST['msg'];
            $query = "Select nome as Nome From provedor where id='".$id_provedor."'";
            echo $query;
            echo "<br>".$mensagem."<br>".$id_provedor;
            //$res_query = ($ligacao_feed, $query);

        ?>
```

Comment: You never read in the value from the `provedor` field.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML form... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($ligacao_feed))` to `mysqli_query()`. You now have enough to debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `select` `name` is `provedor`, however you are using `id` in your `$_POST` assignment:

`$id_provedor = $_POST['id'];`

Should be

`$id_provedor = $_POST['provedor'];`

Comment: Ty, such a noob error but thats not the only problem i had to create a variable to contain the value of $provedor['ID'], but is working now